# How to share Maven archetypes?

Tags: java, maven, nexus, maven-archetype

I've created a Maven archetype which I want to share within my company. To do so, I deployed it to our Nexus server and it can be used from there, but it is somewhat inconvenient since it seems not to be in the catalog of known archetyps on other machines. The workaround is to use it like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://nexus/content/repositories/releases/
```

Would it be possible to use maven without explicitly giving the archtype catalog? I want to use this internal archetype like any other public available archetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

I configure Maven in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` to use the Nexus server as mirror for everything:

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>Nexus</id>
      <name>Nexus Server</name>
      <url>http://nexus/content/repositories/groups/public</url>
      <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

I then put all repos which developers should use in the group `public` (i.e. the proxy repo for Maven Central, my snapshot and release repos, etc).

Nexus will then merge all catalogs (the one from Maven central and the ones from the company repos) into one. That makes all archetypes visible under the default URL.