# How to share a maven archetype via email to be used in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have an eclipse maven-based proyect that I want to share as an example of use of a big library. I have downloaded and installed maven, created an archetype from the proyect (`mvn archetype:create-from-project`), installed it in my local repository (`mvn install`) and tested it (`archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local`).

Now, I want to share the archetype with a few people. I want to send them a file/files that they can add directly to their eclipse environment to create new proyects using my archetype, but I can't find a way. I don't want to set up a remote repository.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just send the pom.xml?

Comment: The archetype creates a directory structure with examples, apart from specifying dependencies. I don't think pom.xml can embed that info, but I'm really a newbie in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this URL is has all the steps to host your archtype to the central repository. Once it is on the central repository, it can be used by any user in their project.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to set up nor use a remote repository. I just want to send the archetype by email to a few known people.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239673/how-to-share-maven-archetypes  follow this question if it helps. Else I do not think there is a way for what you are asking. If you want to keep it safe use a private repo instead of a public repo.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that Maven is a solution to a much bigger task and was never designed for the way I intended to use it.

Maven depends on servers for distribution of artifacts (an archetype is just one kind of artifact) and sending them by email wasn't a planned use case.